# How can I remove html data or text when I click button and replace it with data located in a JSON file array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, button

I am attempting a quote generator that when I click the "Generate quote" button it removes the current quote and author and it replaces it with a new quote and author that I have on a JSON file.
The JSON file is in an array. I want it so that every time I click the button the next quote comes up. Ideally I would like it to randomize and provide any of the quotes available within the JSON Array.

Currently I can click the button and the last quote will appear and for every +1 click the same quote appears because the array is picking up the last item and outputting the quote again.
A temporary, but I believe there is a better workaround, is to have multiple JSON files uploaded and changing the page count in the url from '..quotes-'+pagecount+ '.sjon' to get every quote out.

```
HTML: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Javascript for quote generator-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quoteStyles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="quoteBox" class="quote-text">
    <span id="text"></span>
      <p id="quotePara">


    </p>
    <span id="text2"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-author">
    - <span id="author"></span>
    </div>
      <div class="button-links">

      <button id="getQuote"class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
      </div>
 </body>
 <script src="test.js"></script>
 <script src="http://rogerperez.us/quotes.json"></script>
```

Javascript

```
JavaScript:
 var pageCount = 1;
 var i=0;
 var quotePara = document.getElementById("quotePara");
 var getQuote = document.getElementById("getQuote");

// Request to get json data where the quotes are located
getQuote.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ourRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET','http://rogerperez.us/quotes-1.json');
  ourRequest.onload= function() {
    if (ourRequest.status>= 200 && ourRequest.status<400){
    var ourData= JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
   renderHTML(ourData);
  } else{
    console.log("Connection Error, Please try again.")
  }
  };

  ourRequest.send();
  pageCount++;

  if (pageCount>6){
    getQuote.classList.add('hide-me');
  }
});

console.log(i);

function renderHTML(data){
  var htmlString="";
  var htmlAuthor="";

  // for (j=0;j<data.length;j++){
  //   remove
  // }
  for (i=0;i<data.length; i++){
    console.log("first",i);
    htmlString=data[i].quote;
   htmlAuthor=data[i].author;
    console.log(i);
  }
  quotePara.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
  author.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlAuthor);

}
```

Json

```
[
 {"quote": "Success is not final; failure is not fatal: It is the courage to 
 continue that counts.",
  "author": "Winston S. Churchill"},
  {"quote":"Don't be afraid to give up the good to go for the great.",
"author":"John D. Rockefeller"},
 {"quote":"I find that the harder I work, the more luck I seem to have.",
"author":"Thomas Jefferson"},
 {"quote":"Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.",
"author":"Albert Einstein"},
 {"quote":"o one thing every day that scares you.",
"author":"Anonymous"},
 {"quote":"If you really look closely, most overnight successes took a long 
time.",
"author":"Steve Jobs"},
  {"quote":"The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.",
"author":"Barack Obama"},
  {"quote":"The successful warrior is the average man, with laser-like focus.",
"author":"Bruce Lee"},
  {"quote":"If you really want to do something, you'll find a way. If you don't, you'll find an excuse.",
"author":"Jim Rohn"},
  {"quote":"Be the type of person that when your feet hit the floor in the 
morning the devil says,aww shit.. they are up",
    "author":"Dwayne (The Rock) Johnson"},
  {"quote":"Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close 
they were to success when they gave up",
    "author":"Thomas Edison"},
  {"quote":"Opportunities don't happen. You create them",
    "author":"Chris Grosser"},
  {"quote":"I would rather risk wearing out than rusting out.",
    "author":"Theodore Roosevelt"},
  {"quote":"When you play, play hard; when you work, don't play at all.",
   "author":"Theodore Roosevelt"}
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble is that you're iterating through the whole data array, replacing your variable values, and then only retaining the value of the very last data value:

```
// your code
  for (i=0;i<data.length; i++){
    console.log("first",i);
    htmlString=data[i].quote;
   htmlAuthor=data[i].author;
    console.log(i);
  }
  quotePara.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
  author.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlAuthor);
```

If you wanted to, for instance, make the pageCount array index quote show, you would just do:

```
  // I recommend textContent instead
  quotePara.textContent = data[pageCount].quote;
  author.textContent = data[pageCount].author;
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight and get back to you. Thank you for taking your time in helping me.

Comment: That worked. I moved the page count down so it would start at 0 and so I can use the data.length rather than a fixed number.

Comment: Great to hear! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what the objective is here. But here is my 5 cents worth.

1. The json can be just added to the code - If this is preset as per your example then just load it with the HTML. It would be smarter to append it server side and simpler. If you want to make it an ajax http request do it once at the start of your code when the button is clicked, cache it in a varible and next time the button is clicked before you do your ajax request check if the varible already has it.
2. Your var i being the current Quote index needs to be incremented on the button click see my code - if this is to be random, comment and I will adjust.
3. I have simplified the rendering. If you want some fancy rendering, ie you want to render all of the quotes as they are requested again comment and I will adjust

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p13c8L2w/2/

```
var QUOTES = [{
  "quote": "Success is not final; failure is not fatal: It is the courage to  continue that counts.",
  "author": "Winston S. Churchill"
}, {
  "quote": "Don't be afraid to give up the good to go for the great.",
  "author": "John D. Rockefeller"
}, {
  "quote": "I find that the harder I work, the more luck I seem to have.",
  "author": "Thomas Jefferson"
}, {
  "quote": "Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.",
  "author": "Albert Einstein"
}, {
  "quote": "o one thing every day that scares you.",
  "author": "Anonymous"
}, {
  "quote": "If you really look closely, most overnight successes took a long time.",
  "author": "Steve Jobs"
}, {
  "quote": "The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.",
  "author": "Barack Obama"
}, {
  "quote": "The successful warrior is the average man, with laser-like focus.",
  "author": "Bruce Lee"
}, {
  "quote": "If you really want to do something, you'll find a way. If you don't, you'll find an excuse.",
  "author": "Jim Rohn"
}, {
  "quote": "Be the type of person that when your feet hit the floor in the morning the devil says,aww shit.. they are up",
  "author": "Dwayne (The Rock) Johnson"
}, {
  "quote": "Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up",
  "author": "Thomas Edison"
}, {
  "quote": "Opportunities don't happen. You create them",
  "author": "Chris Grosser"
}, {
  "quote": "I would rather risk wearing out than rusting out.",
  "author": "Theodore Roosevelt"
}, {
  "quote": "When you play, play hard; when you work, don't play at all.",
  "author": "Theodore Roosevelt"
}];


var i = 0;
var quotePara = document.getElementById("quotePara");
var getQuote = document.getElementById("getQuote");

// Request to get json data where the quotes are located
getQuote.addEventListener("click", function() {
  renderHTML(QUOTES);
  // if the current index is the end restart back at 0
  if (i===QUOTES.length) i=0;
});


function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = "";
  var htmlAuthor = "";

  htmlString = data[i].quote;
  htmlAuthor = data[i].author;
  // i'm just fetching the next quote, for a random quote I would just use
  // some random number logic from 0-length of quotes,
  i++;
  // I'm just building some html to show the quote
  quotePara.innerHTML= ["<h2>", htmlString, "</h2>", htmlAuthor].join("");

}
```

Comment: The purpose is to use the following together to exactly what you did under the js fiddle. I need to obtain outside info from an API/Data page through javascript and then output it to the html every time I click the button. When I click the button it should remove the old text and replace it with the next position of the data within the array.

Comment: If the data is coming every time the button is clicked how do we circle the data - since it will be changed, do you want one random quote picked.

Comment: Do you need it to make the api call when the button is clicked on can it do it before and work ahead of the user - since the ajax call will take 300-500ms or more to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I create simple loop with call function `renderHTML`

Here is my fiddle:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkoori123/sc0hebcm/)

```js
var QUOTES = [{
  "quote": "Success is not final; failure is not fatal: It is the courage to  continue that counts.",
  "author": "Winston S. Churchill"
}, {
  "quote": "Don't be afraid to give up the good to go for the great.",
  "author": "John D. Rockefeller"
}, {
  "quote": "I find that the harder I work, the more luck I seem to have.",
  "author": "Thomas Jefferson"
}, {
  "quote": "Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.",
  "author": "Albert Einstein"
}, {
  "quote": "o one thing every day that scares you.",
  "author": "Anonymous"
}, {
  "quote": "If you really look closely, most overnight successes took a long time.",
  "author": "Steve Jobs"
}, {
  "quote": "The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.",
  "author": "Barack Obama"
}, {
  "quote": "The successful warrior is the average man, with laser-like focus.",
  "author": "Bruce Lee"
}, {
  "quote": "If you really want to do something, you'll find a way. If you don't, you'll find an excuse.",
  "author": "Jim Rohn"
}, {
  "quote": "Be the type of person that when your feet hit the floor in the morning the devil says,aww shit.. they are up",
  "author": "Dwayne (The Rock) Johnson"
}, {
  "quote": "Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up",
  "author": "Thomas Edison"
}, {
  "quote": "Opportunities don't happen. You create them",
  "author": "Chris Grosser"
}, {
  "quote": "I would rather risk wearing out than rusting out.",
  "author": "Theodore Roosevelt"
}, {
  "quote": "When you play, play hard; when you work, don't play at all.",
  "author": "Theodore Roosevelt"
}];




var pageCount = -1;
var getQuote = document.getElementById("getQuote");

// Request to get json data where the quotes are located
getQuote.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (pageCount===QUOTES.length) pageCount=-1;
  pageCount++;
 renderHTML(pageCount,QUOTES);
});



function renderHTML(i,data) {
  var htmlString = "";
  var htmlAuthor = "";

  htmlString = data[i].quote;
  htmlAuthor = data[i].author;

 document.getElementById("quote").innerText = htmlString;
  document.getElementById("author").innerText = htmlAuthor;
 document.getElementById("page-num").innerText = i;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="quote"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="author"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="page-num"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="getQuote"class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
</div>
```

if you dont need loop, simply you can call function `renderHTML` when `pageCount!=QUOTES.length`

Comment: @kooroosh-safeashrafi. Your code is really helpful. What I am trying to do is get the data from an outside file with JSON data. I can attempt to do it within the js file, but part of my project is to obtain the info from an API or JSON file.

Comment: If your problem is getting JSON data, read this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_http). and if there was any problem replay this